# error: pathspec 'stable/icehouse' did not match any files known to git. I am getting this error when i execute ./stack.sh

Tags: openstack

error: pathspec 'stable/icehouse' did not match any files known to git. I am

getting this error when i execute ./stack.sh. Please help me to fix this

Comment: You should consider edit the title and add some more detail to your question.

Comment: I have executed the cmd , ./stack.sh to install stack, while it was cloning into /opt/stack/keystone, i am getting this  "error: pathspec 'stable/icehouse' did not match any files known to git "

Answer (score 0):

From what I realized the Icehouse version was removed as a branch from the OpenStack/DevStack repository. Now it is available as a tag (here: https://github.com/openstack-dev/devstack/tree/icehouse-eol).

I cloned the full repository, changed the HEAD to this tag (via git checkout tags/icehouse-eol), and executed the script stack.sh. I ended up with the error:

```
+ git checkout stable/icehouse
error: pathspec 'stable/icehouse' did not match any file(s) known to git.
+ exit_trap
```

In other words I believe the script is broken, it is trying to download the sources from the old repositories that apparently do not exist anymore. Unless you are willing to manually download the sources and somehow modify the script, I do not think the solution is straightforward.